# GCM IntentService registration ID different every time

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I have a quick question: does the token I receive in onRegistered callback is different every time the service is registered? Is that normal? I register the service by:

```
GCMRegistrar.register(mContext, SENDER_ID);
```

Thanks

Comment: It should be the same every time.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Dont call the register method each time. Call it only if required.

    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(c);
    if (regId.equals(""))
    {
        GCMRegistrar.register(<your context>, <Your GCM sender ID>); 
    }
    else
    {
        //already registered
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally it will be the same every time, however Google might refresh their `registration id` records and if this happened you will receive a new registration id.

That's why in your application you call `register` every time and check if the `registration id` changed or no

I have notice that when you uninstall and re-install the app, the `registration id` usually changes.